# Which form is correct? Verb nach und

Tags: grammaticality

I have a question regarding a pretty simple german sentence. Which form is correct or better (or more correct)?

> Dort konnte ich ein paar Kontakte knüpfen und mich unterhalten, mit anderen Leuten die den gleichen Beruf erlernen.

or:

> Dort konnte ich ein paar Kontakte knüpfen und mich mit anderen Leuten unterhalten, die den gleichen Beruf erlernen.

I guess the 2<sup>nd</sup>, but I made that mistake at a german test, and wrote the first sentence. I don't really know why. Maybe because I thought that after *"und"* the verb is 2<sup>nd</sup>. Is the first version somehow acceptable too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence needs a comma before *die den*. But in general, both are okay. The second one is what you will learn in a German course, but the first one is what you will encounter on the street.

The first one could be rewritten as:

> Dort konnte ich ein paar Kontakte knüpfen und mich unterhalten **. Ich konnte mich** mit anderen Leuten **unterhalten**, die den gleichen Beruf erlernen."

As you see, it's two concatenated main clauses with a pretty complicated ellipsis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do you think that first sentence will be somehow accepted? It was an "Aufnahmeprüfung" for a school spot.

Comment: If the auditor acts reasonable, yes. You may get a mark for the missing comma, though.

Comment: I wouldn't accept the first sentence. I am very strict in this case. And the point with the mentioned comma is absolutely right. - But don't mind, there are so many people with German   mother language  who are making even more horrible mistakes. Perhaps I could close an eye, if you made a double point after unterhalten ... in the first version, I mean.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Confused a bit by your remark about a "double point" (I assume a colon?). Could you elaborate how it would fit in the sentence (regarding its meaning)? It doesn't seem it would perform any of the functions of a colon known to me there. Unless the answer is a bit too long for a comment, in this case I can ask a proper question.

Comment: You are right. I meant a colon. And I was wrong: The sentence after the colon wouldn‘t be a full sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is more correct!

The first could rather be acceptable in this form:

> Dort konnte ich ein paar Kontakte knüpfen und mich unterhalten -
>    mit anderen Leuten, die den gleichen Beruf erlernen.

(This would emphasize the point that those were people of the same profession.)